# What was the death rate of Germans outside Germany's post war border after World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, europe, germany, post-war

In 1945, how many Germans were living in areas of eastern and central Europe outside Germany's post 1945 border?

How many of them died an 'unnatural' death (i.e. by murder, starvation, disease, execution, overwork in labour camps, etc)?

How did this death rate compare to:

1. the post war death rate of the area they lived in or were expelled from?
2. the death rate of Germans who came from *within* Germany's new border?
3. the death rate in Britain, France, America, etc?

Edit: I'm trying to establish whether there's any justice to the claim that these Germans were the victims of genocide. This is a common claim by holocaust deniers, although of course even if it were true, that doesn't mean there was no Holocaust.

If there was a campaign of genocide, we should expect that these ethnic Germans were more likely to get killed than other racial groups in contemporary Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Check these two links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volga_Germans
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_and_expulsion_of_Germans_(1944%E2%80%9350)

Germans were subject of expulsion or even genocide during the war, while soviet troops were entering to territories inhabited by germans. But after the war they were not killed in masse, except in the Soviet Union, where former prisioners of war died in great numbers. Also germans of Volga and from the baltic states were expulsed from their lands and their number was reduced as result.
Since most germans were expulsed from eastern Europe, is difficult to estimate a death rate in those countries, because after the war no german was living there.

Maybe you won't find a higher death rate after the war outside the Soviet Union. But for those who died in the gulag you might use this [graph](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gulag_mortality_rate_1934_1953.PNG) as reference.

Comment: Were the death rates of ethnic Germans different from those of other peoples living under Soviet rule?  E.g. the Ukranian Holodomor (though that was pre-WWII).

Comment: @jamesqf Indeed, gulag deaths are different compared to the Holomodor. The gulag was comparable to a concentration camp, where only enemies of the state (real or not) died. While the Holomodor might be similar to the Great Leap Forward, because it killed people without any discern. All these events might be called genocides.